# Three.JS - Different shaders for different objects

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to blur multiple meshes in three.js, each with a different amount of blurring. I've got an EffectComposer that uses the HorizontalBlurShader and the VerticalBlurShader that are used in the examples. Any ideas on how I'd go about doing this? Would I use multiple scenes? Do I render to a target or directly to the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like one of those *it depends* kind of problems.

What effect are you trying to achieve? Do the shapes interest? How are they going to blur if they intersect?

The first thought that comes to mind is how I'd do this in Photoshop. I'd put each shape on it's own layer and apply a blur filter to each layer. That would correspond in three.js to making one scene per shape, drawing each shape to a render target, blurring that target, then drawing that target into the canvas (or yet another target). Effectively rendering 3d shapes each one at a time into a 2d texture, blurring the texture, then drawing each texture. It would provide the same look as if you had put each shape in it's own layer in photoshop and applied a different blur to each layer.

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing. The tricky part was determining when to call "clear" and when not to "clear" on a Pass. For some reason renderer.clearTarget didn't work for me so I had to selectively enable clear for the render pass on my last time through the composer otherwise I'd get a non-stop additive effect.